# How to disable Paypal auto inovice generator in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, invoice, paypal

i am using magento 2 where using paypal while order placed invoice generated automatically how to stop i want to generate it later from admin manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the payment action to `Authorization` in this case payment will only authorize not capture(not generate Invoice). But make sure that you know the difference between payment actions.

**EDIT**

`Store > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > PayPal Express Checkout > Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout > Payment Action to Authorization.`

[image]

Comment: how can i do that can you guide me ?

Comment: See my edit.. @ShubhajayDas

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My requirement  is to stop auto invoice generation programmatically after successful  payment because invoice generation part will be taken care by an ERP system.

Comment: Yes, please do the change as I said and try it will work :) @ShubhajayDas

Comment: i have checked with that changes as you said.After successful orderplace when i am  open adminpanel and try to check that order it shows a white p[age only with this message "Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving."